# Clustering a set of points with circles

Tags: algorithm, cluster-computing, k-means

I have a group of 100 points in a 2-D plane with known x-y coordinates . I want to draw 25 circles such that exactly 4 points are present in each circle.Each point has to be in exactly one circle. Can you provide the basic algorithm as to how to proceed.

Note: I have been looking at some algorithms which involve k-means ,but none had exactly what I want. I know python/go/matlab/c in case there are some specific modules in that language which could be of use.

Comment: Clustering is the wrong tool. You are looking at a **set cover** problem, which is NP-hard unfortunately. You probably cannot use k-means or any other clustering algorithm here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are some configurations that would have no solution.

[image: Impossible example with 20 points]

Any hill-climbing algorithm could get stuck in a local maximum.

You could enumerate all combinations of 4 point groups and try to fit circles round each of the groups, but even then the tightest circles may not lead to a solution, when a looser-fitting circle might. And the combinatorial explosion may make this method unfeasible.